# Windows 10: Setting Acrobat Reader as Default PDF Reader from Batch File

Tags: windows, pdf, file-association

I need to set up multiple machines with Acrobat Reader, and need to do it again after they have been re-imaged. I have no control over the image.

I understood that the `assoc` command can be used to associate a file type, and I have managed to do that with the `.eml` extension:

```
assoc .eml=txtfile
```

However, I have not had the same success with the `.pdf` extension:

```
assoc .pdf=AcroExch.Document.DC
```

I got the above value using the `ftype` command. I have run the batch file as administrator.

What is the most reliable to set the association from a batch file?